# Test case failing in CI

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, enzyme

> Error: expect(value).toMatchSnapshot()

Received value does not match stored `snapshot` 1.

```
- Snapshot

+ Received

@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
(48 more lines...)
```

The above error I'm getting when it is run on `CI`.

But in local all test cases are passing.

Junit Parser is using as CI system here.

Bellow code is my test case

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { CyberHistogram } from '../../../../components/dashboard/cyberHistogram';
import {
  mockThreats,
  mockKeys,
} from '../../../testConstants';

describe('CyberHistogram', () => {
  it('canary', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
  it('matches snapshot', () => {
    expect(shallow(
      <CyberHistogram
        threatData={mockThreats}
        keys={mockKeys}
      />,
    )).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: In the current state, this question should be closed, since it can't be realistically answered. We don't know how your tests looks, neither *what* CI system you are using. Could you please add more detail for the question to be answered?

Comment: Please don't add these details as comments, but rather *edit* your question.